# Under what conditions can an NSWindowController's document change?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

My app observes the `document` property of its `NSWindowController` and performs some UI setup when it is set. Once it has been set, it would be difficult to rebuild the UI (for internal reasons) as the result of a change.

Once an `NSWindowController` has set its `document` property to an opened document, under what conditions will the system ever *change* that property to a new `NSDocument` instance (i.e., will the document ever be swapped out)? I've never observed it happening, but I can imagine features like versions or iCloud syncing causing the window controller's document to get swapped for a new document. However, the documentation on the `NSWindowController` lifecycle doesn't seem to touch on the issue.

Comment: It will change only once and this is guaranteed by Document method - (void)makeWindowControllers where you call addWindowController:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't change once it has been set. NSWindowController gets its document by `addWindowController` method. Every new/opened document creates it's own windowController. Instance of document doesn't change with iCloud or revertChanges. It is up to you how to synchronise document with its views (redrawing).

```
/* Create the user interface for this document, but don't show it yet. 
The default implementation of this method invokes [self windowNibName], 
creates a new window controller using the resulting nib name (if it is not nil), 
specifying this document as the nib file's owner, and then invokes [self addWindowController:theNewWindowController] to attach it. You can override 
this method to use a custom subclass of NSWindowController or to create more 
than one window controller right away. NSDocumentController invokes this method 
when creating or opening new documents.
*/


// e.g. override 
- (void)makeWindowControllers
{
    if ([[self windowControllers] count] == 0) {
        MainWindowController *controller = [[MainWindowController alloc] init];
        [self addWindowController:controller];
    }
}
```